# Confusion about how an @autowire declaration is placed on a protected variable of a parent class/interface. How is this being autowired?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, autowired

I have inherited some Spring MVC project code.

There is an MVC `PortfolioController` in which a handler method called `aggregate()` uses a `user` object variable freely through out the method. Its declaration is not listed any where in `PortfolioContoller` class but when I rightclick it eclipse say's it's Autowired. I click on it and it takes me to the spring xml file the user variable type is declared in. (the type is UserInfo).
The actual user variable declaration exists in a parent `AbstractGenericController` class that is actually residing in a completely different project package called commons.  And oddly the user variable is marked **protected**. Even the getter getUser() is marked protected. 
I am assuming since PortfolioController is extending the GenericController Spring know’s how to autowire an object even if it’s in a different project package (commons). 
Is this the reason Spring is able to autowire the protected member or is it because of some maven magic where we install commons and it gets somehow packaged in with the MVC controllers project?

Comment: Spring can autowire private and protected members.  Spring knows about it because it's a member of `PortfolioController` (by virtue of being inherited from `AbstractGenericController`)

Comment: But AbstractGenericController is in a completely different project called commons. I am using maven. So I guess there is some maven magic going on.

Comment: Maven isn't magic, in all likelihood there's a dependency from your project to the commons project either directly specified in your pom or picked up transitively via another dependency.  If you do a `mvn dependency:tree` you'll see the full dependency graph.

Comment: It's not magic and has nothing to do with Maven.  Because your controller extends the generic controller it inherits all the properties associated with the superclass.

Comment: But, the superclass is not in the same package and the variable declaration of user is of protected scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Spring performs autowiring is with a [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html), specifically the [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html), which works using the Java Reflection API.

It's really quite simple, `BeanPostProcessor`s run after the beans are instantiated, so in the case of `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, given a bean it gets its fields, checks for the presence of the `@Autowired` annotation and assigns a suitable object to it, something like this:

```
for (Field field : bean.getClass().getDelcaredFields())
{
  if (field.getAnnotation(Autowired.class) != null)
  {
    boolean wasAccessible = field.isAccessible();

    try
    {
      field.setAccessible(true);
      field.set(bean, findSuitableValueByType(field.getType())); 
    }
    finally
    {
      field.setAccessible(wasAccessible);
    }  
  }
}
```

There's a little more to it than that, as you need to walk the inheritance hierarchy graph because `getDeclaredMethods` only returns the fields for the given class (but importantly returns all the fields regardless of there access modifiers) and obviously `@Autowired` can be applied to more than just fields, but you get the gist.

Comment: But in my case, the protected user variable is declared in a parent class, that is in a completely different project..

Comment: That's irrelevant, the parent class must be on your classpath either as a reference to a JAR containing it or the root directory it was compiled to.  If it wasn't you'd get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: I Gotcha Nick! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since the variable is protected in the superclass it is accessible in subclasses.

Using some reflection magic, spring instantiates the class and sets the user attribute. For this, the above wouldn't even need to be true; private methods are accessible through reflection if you have access to the class.

Answer (score 1):

It is done via reflection, Spring can also wire private variables as well.  If you don't like this approach, you can do it via a setter:

```
private Something something;

@Autowired
public void setSomething(Something something) {
    this.something = something;
}
```

or using the constructors:

```
private Something something;

@Autowired
public SomethingElse(Something something) {
    this.something = something;
}
```